# Почему выполняется со второго клика и как исправить?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gson

Есть поле address(TextView). Нужно вывести данные по выполнению запроса.
Запрос google -> разбор json -> вывод в textview.
Установлен слушатель на нажатие карты, но выполняется запись в textview со второго клика.

> MapsActivity.kt

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        val addressTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.address)
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(53.7095281, 91.4277445), 12f))
        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener { latLng ->

                googleMap.clear()// очистка карты от маркеров
                googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(latLng)).isVisible = true //добавляет маркер по нажатию

            var location = LatLng(53.402971, 91.083748)
//координаты первой точки
                 var lat1 = location!!.latitude
                 var lng1 = location!!.longitude

                //координаты второй точки
                 var lat2 = latLng!!.latitude
                 var lng2 = latLng!!.longitude
                "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?language=ru&units=metric&origins=$lat1,$lng1&DC&destinations=$lat2,$lng2&mode=driving&key=AIzaSyCJYCg5StSenKMjLgEn3zAbAAwpuBESKQc".httpGet().responseString { _, _, result ->

                    when (result) {
                        is Result.Failure -> {

                        }
                        is Result.Success -> {

                            val builder = GsonBuilder()
                            val gson: Gson = builder.create()
                            val resp = JSONObject(result.value)
                            val rows = resp.getJSONArray("rows")
                            val rowjObj = rows.getJSONObject(0)
                            val elements = rowjObj.getJSONArray("elements")
                            val elementsObj = elements.getJSONObject(0)
                            val distance = elementsObj.getJSONObject("distance")
                            var value = distance.getInt("value")

                            val deSerial = gson.fromJson(result.value, Data::class.java)
                            val valueAddress = deSerial.destination_addresses
                            val valueArr = valueAddress[0]

                            addressTextView.text = "dhddg"

                            value /= 1000
                            GLOBAL_VAR = value.toString()
                            GLOBAL_ADDRESS = valueArr

                            println(value)
                            println(valueArr)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }

    }
```

> Дополнение.
>    Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

```
10-18 14:11:38.223 19506-20275/com.example.sfp.coal D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xaf215c80: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
10-18 14:11:38.254 19506-20275/com.example.sfp.coal D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf215c80: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xa27ff750)
10-18 14:11:38.277 19506-19545/com.example.sfp.coal E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa27ce8c0
10-18 14:11:40.161 19506-20277/com.example.sfp.coal W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
10-18 14:11:40.168 19506-20277/com.example.sfp.coal I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
10-18 14:11:40.168 19506-20277/com.example.sfp.coal I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
10-18 14:11:40.178 19506-20277/com.example.sfp.coal W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000001/n/x86
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6556)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:942)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5081)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:12713)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:12677)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:12661)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:7159)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4342)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4199)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4174)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at com.example.sfp.coal.MapsActivity$onMapReady$1$1.invoke(MapsActivity.kt:91)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at com.example.sfp.coal.MapsActivity$onMapReady$1$1.invoke(MapsActivity.kt:28)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$1.invoke(Deserializable.kt:37)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$1.invoke(Deserializable.kt)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$5$1.invoke(Deserializable.kt:62)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$5$1.invoke(Deserializable.kt)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.Request$callback$1.run(Request.kt:225)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DefaultEnvironment$callbackExecutor$1.execute(Environment.kt:16)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.Request.callback(Request.kt:224)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$5.invoke(Deserializable.kt:60)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$5.invoke(Deserializable.kt)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.requests.AsyncTaskRequest.call(AsyncTaskRequest.kt:12)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.requests.AsyncTaskRequest.call(AsyncTaskRequest.kt:6)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.FuelManager$executor$2$1$1.run(FuelManager.kt:48)
10-18 14:11:40.316 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-18 14:11:40.317 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal I/System.out: 54
10-18 14:11:40.317 19506-20308/com.example.sfp.coal I/System.out: ул. Гоголя, 6, Абакан, Респ. Хакасия, Россия, 655002
```

Comment: А какое отношение к вопросу имеет java и android studio?

Comment: @post_zeew, среда разработки - Android Studio.
Язык может быть и java.

Comment: Метка андроид-студио служит для вопросов типа "как добавить свои Hot-key", "быстро сделать геттер" и т.д. для вашего вопроса она не нужна, потому что IDE на код не влияет. Метку java считаю допустимой, ведь можно писать на xamarin, kotlin..

Comment: @Flippy, на будущее учту.

Comment: @Flippy так ведь он на kotlin и пишет в вопросе, зачем метка java?

Comment: @eugeneek, поспешил )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос.
Нужно перенести выполнение записи текста в основной поток.

```
runOnUiThread { address.text = valueArr }
```